# Function `axis` behaves unexpectedly for noninteger values of parameter `mgp[3]`

Tags: r, plot, graphics, axis

`?par` says this about `mgp[1:3]`:

> The margin line (in mex units) for the axis title, axis labels and axis line. Note that mgp[1] affects title whereas mgp[2:3] affect axis. The default is c(3, 1, 0).

`?axis` says something similar. However, it seems that tick labels are *not* in general placed at line `mgp[2]`, but rather at line `mgp[2] + (mgp[3] %% 1)`. Thus, `axis` seems to behave as documented only when `mgp[3]` is an integer. Is this a bug in `axis`, or is something else going on?

Here is an example showing expected and actual output of `axis` for integer and noninteger `mgp[3]`:

```r
par(mar = c(5, 1, 5, 1))
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
box(lty = 3)

## 'axis' puts line and labels in right place when 'mgp[3]' is integer
mgp_bottom <- c(0, 2.5, 1) # 'mgp[1]' is arbitrary
axis(side = 1, mgp = mgp_bottom)
mtext(c("labels", "line"), side = 1, line = mgp_bottom[2:3]) 

## 'axis' puts line in right place when 'mgp[3]' is noninteger,
## but apparently not labels
mgp_top <- mgp_bottom - c(0, 0, 1e-3)
axis(side = 3, mgp = mgp_top)
mtext(c("labels", "line"), side = 3, line = mgp_top[2:3])
mtext("LABELS", side = 3, line = mgp_top[2] + (mgp_top[3] %% 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does look like a bug.  I think it happens here:  https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/6e61247f042985d5cb9f09034cb9e694a69082e0/src/library/graphics/src/plot.c#L944-L948 .  In this context, `gpptr(dd)->mgp[2]` is the value of `par("mgp")[3]`, and is a double.  Here it's converted to an int, which loses the fractional part.

I don't really understand what the intention is in this calculation, so I'm not sure that simply changing `lineoff` to a double wouldn't cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for submitting the bug report! The double-to-int conversion inside of `C_axis` does seem to be the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

This has been reported to R's bugzilla, in PR#18194, i.e.,
https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18194

and fixed in the R sources, svn 80947, now.

Comment: and now back ported to 'R 4.1.1 patched' , i.e., will be fixed in the upcoming R 4.1.2 release.